# Fabric fab -f : Can't find any collection named 'fabfile'

Tags: python, fabric

After updated `Fabric` from 1.4 to 2.4, `fab -f <file_path>.<fabfile>.py` isn't working anymore. It always throws the error `Can't find any collection named 'fabfile'!`

From `fab --help`, it stated that `-f` option is used to `-f STRING, --config=STRING         Runtime configuration file to use.`

Thinking to downgrade it to 1.4 since all my project on other hosts are running this version. But i cant't get back the 1.4 installer on net. Anyone could help on this or any workaround for fabric 2.4 ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is indeed changed! 
Now with newer version of Fabric 2.x you must use `-r` instead of `-f`. This is based on `pyinvoke` check this link [pyInvoke](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/latest/invoke.html#cmdoption-r)

For example: if you are in `dir A` and your fabfile is in dir B

```
dir A
|__dir B
```

you will be able to call your fabfile tasks by executing this command from the command-line

```
fab -r ./b/ yourTaskName
```

Comment: You're right! I just found out this prrviously myself, ended up i downgraded it back to 1.x

Comment: I had the same problem previously, but I have done is reading the changelog on their site. Then I found inside the changelog that is replaced by -f! 
Now, I have everything in fabric, which is imo much better than fabric1

Comment: Wait, does this mean that -f doesn't work anymore? The only valid name is fabfile.py and if I want to have multiple fabfiles I must have multiple directories each with separate fabfile.py?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be working, yet it is displayed in the "Core options" with `fab2 --help`.